# How to know saltstack tool TCP port

Tags: linux, firewall, firewalld

When I stop the firewall service, salt master is working well. I recieved answer from the salt minion. When I start the firewall salt can not connect to the minion anymore.

I didn't change the TCP port in the default configuration of salt master. So I should open the TCP port 4505 and 4506.
I did it with these commands :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=private --add-port=4505-4506/tcp 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Salt can not connect the minion with this rule.

I'm using Suse. I believe SuSEfirewall2 is not used anymore in this kind of distribution. The binary is not present in my system.

Comment: Can you tell me the `iptables -L -n|grep 4505` output?

Comment: Which machine did you configure the firewall service?  The Salt master?  The servers running minions?

Comment: I corrected my post. `iptables -L -n |grep 4505` tells nothing

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue in adding the rules in the public zone and the private zone

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=private --add-port=4505-4506/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=4505-4506/tcp  
firewall-cmd --reload
```

After that the salt master can ping the salt minion